# Triple integral - ellipsoid - check answer

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

I need to evaluate the triple integral of the function $$f(x,y,z) = z$$ over the area/body $Q$ (where $Q \subset \mathbb{R}^3$) which is enclosed by the ellipsoid

$x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 = 1$

Here $a,b,c$ are positive constants.

I am getting zero and to me it kind of makes sense because this body is so to speak symmetrical w.r.t. $z$. I mean when the point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is in $Q$, so is $(x_0, y_0, -z_0)$.

But my book is giving this answer: $abc^2 \cdot \pi/4$

Which one is correct?

Did they mean in the book to just integrate over this part of Q which is above the Oxy plane?
Or am I missing something else?

Comment: You are right that the integral over $Q$ is zero. The suggested solution $\dfrac{abc^2\pi}4$ does agree with the part of $Q$ above the plane $z=0$, so your suspicion may be correct.

Comment: @user170231 if we consider the part above $z=0$, shouldn't the result be $abc^2\pi /2$? What am I missing?

Comment: @SineoftheTime I checked the integral against Mathematica (and I trust it in this case). I get the same result by hand when converting to cylindrical coordinates $(x,y,z)=(ar\cos(\theta),br\sin(\theta),c\zeta)$.

Comment: @user170231 yes, you're right. my bad

Comment: @user170231 Is this actually cylindrical coordinates? If I do this substitution I get zero on step 2 i.e. after integrating by $z$. Strange... I guess I am making some mistake. Now I realized I cannot even solve it with the assumption that Q is above the plane Oxy. I will try some more.

Comment: Anyway, I got the answer from the book assuming that $Q$ is only the part above the Oxy plane. But I am not quite sure why we can use this substitution. So I asked another question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4644512/bijective-mapping-substitution-proof

Comment: $$\int _{-a}^a\int _{-\frac{b \sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a}}^{\frac{b \sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a}}\int _0^{\frac{c \sqrt{a^2 b^2-a^2 y^2-b^2 x^2}}{a b}}f(x,y,z)dzdydx=\frac{\pi}{4}   a b c^2$$

Comment: It's not standard cylindrical coordinates, but *cylindrical enough*. I'm tempted to call it ["elliptic-cylindrical"](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticCylinder.html) but this name is already used [elsewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_cylindrical_coordinates). Anyway, the only difference is scaling of the axes. The integral over $Q$ transforms to$$\iiint_Q z\,dx\,dy\,dz = abc\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_{-c\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{c\sqrt{1-r^2}}r\zeta\,d\zeta\,dr\,d\theta$$and the lower limit for $\zeta$ would be $0$ if you integrate only over the top half of $Q$.

Comment: @user170231 your solution can't be correct.
If a, b, c all have the unit $[m]$ the triple integral must have unit $[m^4]$.
But your integral has unit $[m^5]$.

Comment: @gpmath You're right, I'm not sure how I made that error. I of course meant$$abc^2 \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}r\zeta\,d\zeta\,dr\,d\theta$$